# Movie where the protagonist wakes up as a female character completely nude and finds armor to put on and a sword in virtual reality

Tags: story-identification, movie, virtual-worlds

The scene has a very warm orange tint lighting. The protagonist is a guy that visits a virtual reality world but wakes up in a blonde female avatar/body completely naked on a canopy bed with several other nude females. He says something funny and then he finds a set of armor to put on and leaves the area. Later, the female character is wielding a sword in a fight scene. I think the plot involves him trying to catch a criminal but I can’t remember the full plot.

I think the movie came out between 2015 and 2020.

Comment: Do you know what country the film was from? What language?

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/20774) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Answer (score 14):

Is this ***[Virtual Revolution](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt4054004/)*** (2016), also known as *2047: Virtual Revolution*...?

> In a future mega city, where most people spend most time hooked up to a virtual world, an agent, employed by a corporation supplying virtual reality, is busy tracking down killers/terrorists, both in the virtual and real world.

The film is set in a futuristic version of Paris that bears a striking resemblance to the version of Los Angeles depicted in *Blade Runner*. In this world, 75% of people spend almost all their time logged into virtual reality massively multiplayer online role-playing games known as 'Verses;' these people are known as the 'Connected.'

The protagonist -- a [Rick Deckard](https://bladerunner.fandom.com/wiki/Rick_Deckard) knock-off called Nash Trenton -- is a 'Hybrid;' someone who spends part of their time in virtual reality and part of it in the real world. When he's in the real world, he works as a shadow agent for a corporation running one of the Verses, but rather than being paid to hunt and kill replicants, his targets are 'Necromancers,' a group of terrorists who've recently been killing Connected individuals with a digital virus.

Around 26 minutes into the film, there's a scene where Trenton logs into a Verse using a Necromancer's equipment and account. He wakes up in the body of a blonde female avatar lying naked in a bed with two other women. He gets out of the bed, looks at his avatar's reflection in a nearby mirror and says "typical," then puts on some clothes -- a mixture of fabric, leather and metal armour -- picks up a firearm and leaves the room.

After that, he meets a male character and they team up together in a fight against other characters, including a mecha-style robot. This specific Verse has urban military sci-fi stylings, so the characters (including Trenton's) use modern/futuristic weaponry, such as firearms and grenades, rather than swords.

When Trenton logs into his own VR account though (which he does repeatedly in the film), he enters a medieval fantasy style Verse in which his character is a male swordsman who travels with a small party of other similarly-themed adventurers. In the opening scene, we see him and his comrades battling a female character who uses both a sword and magic.

There's a brief shot of Trenton waking up as the blonde female avatar at around the 0:29 mark in the trailer below.

Comment: +1 Good answer. This seems terrible though, both the summary and the trailer. As a fan of Blade Runner, the mere existence of this movie offends me :P

Comment: @AndresF. - Well, it *is* kind of a compliment to Blade Runner. Nobody's clamoring to make cheap knock-offs of [Ishtar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ishtar_(film)).